# Using Javascript, how would one export a HTML table as a .DAT file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, export

I've been requested to build, within an angular app, a feature in which the user can export a data table as multiple files, one of which is a dat file. Is this possible to do with an angular directive? Should I be approaching this from the server?

Though having Google'd, I haven't found any resources as yet for doing so, and thus I'm not even sure it is possible.

Comment: You can create and save files from JS https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js